# how can i move the cursor in insert mode in viemu (w/o using the arrow keys)?

Tags: visual-studio, viemu

sometimes i just want to move either left or right a couple of characters (or go to the end of the line) but don't really want to leave insert mode just to move a couple chars.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about viemu and visual studio, but in vim, you can use `<Ctrl-o>` to enter a single command while in insert mode, so `<ctrl-o>2l` will move you 2 characters to the left, and `<ctrl-o>$` will move you to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of moving the cursor which is easier than just using the arrow keys, thats what they are there for. Insert mode is for inserting text, not navigating the file. If you would like to be so pedantic about not using the arrow key then there is a solution for you:

1. press
2. use 'HJKL' keys until at destination
3. press 'i'